# PHP Cannot redirect even if conditions are met

Tags: php, redirect

Here is my code

```
    <?php
      if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }
      if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) { header("Location: index.php");  }
      ob_start();

      if($_POST) {
        $id = $_POST['book_id'];
        $command = $_POST['command'];
        $sourcePage = $_POST['source'];
      } else if ($_GET){
        $command = $_GET['command'];
        $sourcePage = $_GET['source'];
        $id = $_GET['book_id'];
      } else {
        header("Location: index.php");
      }
      // if command is 2 then show cart content
      if($command == 2) {
        showCart();
      // if command is 1 then add book to cart
      } else if($command  == 1) {
        addToCart($id);
       header("Location: $sourcePage");
      // if command is 0, then remove book from cart
      } else if($command == 0) {
        deleteFromCart($id);
        header("Location: $sourcePage");
      } else if(!isset($command)){
        header("Location: index.php");
      }

  ob_flush();
    ?>
```

Why is it that even if I'm not logged in, I'm not redirected?

Comment: remove output buffering .. or let whole code execute also you should use absolute url in header

Comment: You talking about which redirection from all of the above ?

Comment: The first header. Well, actually all of it is not working, but the important one is the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it possible that the page is simply refreshing under the condition that `$_POST` or `$_GET` exists, falling into one of the later `header("Location: ...")` commands?

If so, you'd want to fix the problem by adding a die();

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) { header("Location: index.php"); die(); }
```

Comment: Yay, that solved it. Thankyu. Still I'm kinda surprised that the $_POST and $_GET part is even executed. Shouldn't the second line redirect the page before reaching that part?

Comment: the redirect happens, but the code continues to execute and completes before the redirect does, causing the browser to also receive the 2nd redirect, which is why `die();` fixes the issue (it prevents the 2nd redirect from happening)

Answer (score 1):

Using exit() or die functions may fix the problem. But there is only very very limited amount of situations where actually need to use one of these functions.

I think you can enhance if else conditions by putting some more conditions. But this will increase your lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, every time there is redirect via headers, its following connected code tends to execute.

For example : if you have an `else/else if` along with an `if`(which has the redirect code) then they will also be executed and the redirect never happens. However if you break up the conditions into individual `ifs` then after entering one `if` if a redirect is present such that there is no succeeding code after that header code in the `if` then the redirect will happen.

Better to use `die()`/`exit()` all over to avoid discrepancies.